# converting class component to hooks : useDispatch/useSelector : where to call it and whats is wrong here?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to convert the class component I created to a functional one. Class component is working fine but when I am trying to do same thing using functional way I am not able to get the calls properly. I am trying to load data on ui from the REST call using Axios. useDispatch/useSelector. where to call it and whats is wrong here? I understand that have to use useEffect instead of componentdidmount but I think it's not getting called the way I am trying. Please advice...

Old Class Component code:

```
class MyClassComponent extends Component {
componentDidMount() {
    const { changeRequests, listRequests } = this.props;
    if (!changeRequests.fulfilled) {
      listRequests();
    }
  }
  render() {
      const { changeRequests } = this.props;
      if (!changeRequests.fulfilled) {
      return (
        <CircularProgress />
      )
    }
      return(
       // code
    )
   }      
 }
//useSelector replace mapStateToProps
const mapStateToProps = state => {// onRequest is reducer class
  return {
    changeRequests: state.onRequest.changeRequests
  }
};
//useDispatch replaces
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {// connects with Action class and then with axios DB call
  return {
    listRequests: () => dispatch(fetchRequests())
  }
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyClassComponent));
```

New code I am trying looks like :

```
export default function MyFunctionalComponent() {
const [state, setState] = React.useState({});

useEffect(() => {
const { changeRequests, listRequests } = props;
    if (!changeRequests.fulfilled) {/
      listRequests();
    }
},[]);
const changeRequests = useSelector(state => state.onRequest.changeRequests);

const listRequests = useDispatch(() => {
             fetchPortfolioRequests();
},[]);
return(<h2>{changeRequests.data}</h2>);
```

Comment: What is the error/problem you are facing?

Comment: if (!changeRequests.fulfilled) { was the issue....its working now but have to load <CircularProgress /> yet.Any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
I was getting warning "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency". made following changes in the above code

```
const listRequests = useCallback(() => dispatch(fetchRequests()), [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!changeRequests.fulfilled) {
      listRequests();
    }
  }, [listRequests, changeRequests]);

------
//removed callback from here as we can t use callback or reducer inside useEffect().

    const changeRequests = useSelector(state => state.oncallRequest.changeRequests);

useEffect(() => {
        if (!changeRequests.fulfilled) {
            dispatch(fetchRequests(), [dispatch])// direct called method here for my action
        }
    }, [changeRequests.fulfilled, dispatch]);

// changeRequests.fulfilled is set to true in reducer.

Action class looks like:
fetchRequests = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch({type: LIST_PENDING});

    listChangeRequests().then(data => {
        dispatch({type: LIST_FULFILLED, changeRequests: data})
    }).catch(err => {
        dispatch({type: LIST_FAILED, changeRequests: {error: ""}})
    });
};
````

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `useDispatch` incorrectly.

```
const listRequests = useDispatch(() => {
  fetchPortfolioRequests();
},[]);
```

should be

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const listRequests = useCallback(() => dispatch(fetchPortfolioRequests()),[dispatch]);
```

Also in the class based component, you were using `fetchRequests()` but here you are trying to use `fetchPortfolioRequests()`.

**update**

Your functional component should look like this:

```
export default function MyFunctionalComponent() {


  const changeRequests = useSelector(state => state.onRequest.changeRequests);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const listRequests = useCallback(() => dispatch(fetchPortfolioRequests()), [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!changeRequests.fulfilled) {
      listRequests();
    }
  }, [listRequests, changeRequests]);

  return changeRequests.fulfilled ? <h2>{changeRequests.data}</h2> : <CircularProgress />;

}
```

**update**

if you once want to dispatch when the component renders then you can just use

```
  useEffect(() => {
      listRequests();
  }, [listRequests]);
```

Comment: its working now but have to load <CircularProgress /> yet.Any suggestion

Comment: This looks good but I am stuck with the unlimited number of calls. If I use ```useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchRequests())}
    , []);``` it makes single call but then its diff to get 'CircularProgress'

Comment: @Roy once `listRequests` is called make sure that `fulfilled` is set to true in your reducer.

Comment: @Roy - also see my updated answer if you only want to call it when the component mounts.